# How to automatically connect to public wifi that requires logging in through browser?

Tags: wifi

At my work we use a shared wifi that requires logging in. When starting the computer, it connects to the open wifi but there is no internet. I need to open a browser and enter my work credentials through the login webpage. Only then I can start using the internet.

Is there a way to log in automatically as soon as the computer connects to the public wifi? Or is it all mediated through the browser? (which would be strange because I can close it and still remain connected to the internet)

Answer (score 0):

Connection events can trigger [script execution](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Wpa_supplicant#wpa_cli_action_script) for login, however, you probably don't want your work credentials in a script.